# Strange "Indentation error" in simple recursive function

Tags: python, recursion, indentation

I'm writing a simple class that generates the first `n` lines of the Pascal Triangle using recursion:

```
class PascalTriangle:
    """Returns the first n lines of the Pascal Triangle. Recursive."""

    def __init__ (self, n):
        assert(n > 0)
        self.lst[0][0] = 1
        self.lines = n
        calculate (1)

    def __call__(self, n):
        assert(n > 0)
        self.lst[0][0] = 1
        self.lines = n
        calculate (1)

    def calculate (self, k):
        if k ==  self.lines:
            return self.lst
        else:   
            row = [ ]
            row.append(1)     # <------- line 45
            for  i in range(1, k-1):
                row.append(self.lst[k-1][i-1] + self.lst[k-1][i])
            row.append(1) 
            self.lst.append(row)
            calculate(k+1)

    def printTriangle(self):
        for row in self.lst:
            print(row)


ps = PascalTriangle(2)
ps.printTriangle()

ps3 = PascalTriangle()
ps3(3)          
ps3.printTriangle()
```

I'm getting the following error:

> line 45
>       row.append(1)
>                    .......................^
>   IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level

It has been very frustrating as I can't really see any problems in the indentation. What am I not getting here?

Comment: this error usually means that you provided erroneous indents somewhere in your code. may be 5 spaces, instead of 4 or wrong tabulation. i don't know if stackowerflow shows formatting correctly.

Comment: Sounds like mixed tabs and spaces. The tab/space mixture in the edit view is suspicious.

Comment: I see a mix of tabs and spaces in the code you posted here on SO; see [this screenshot from your text in Sublime Text, where dots are spaces and dashes are tabs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eWSZd.png). Don't do that, configure your editor to only use spaces for indentation.

Comment: toggling *"show invisibles"* (or equivalent) in your editor is crucial for whitespace-sensitive languages